# How to wrap quoted text with span?

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

I have a question, how can add `<span style="color: blue">` to text in quotes.

Example:

```
.. and he said "Hello, I am Nick"
```

Using regex I want to achieve this result:

```
.. and he said <span style="color: blue>"Hello, I am Nick"</span>
```

I want to know how I can do that with regular expressions. Goal is to apply color only to text inside the quotes.

Comment: And what about `he said "Hello \"Whats-your-name\", i am Nick"`?

Comment: I want to know how I can do that with regular expressions find and apply color only to text inside the quotes

Comment: [`string.replace(/(['"])(.*?)\1/g, '<span class="blue">$1$2$1</span>');`](https://jsfiddle.net/4dcpt4ux/)

Comment: @Tushar can you explain what is `\1` is doing there? curious to know

Comment: @Jai the first captured group. If `'` is matched before string, the same `'` will be matched after string and same for `"`. So, this'll work for both `'abcd'` and `"abcd"`.

Comment: @Tushar just read at mdn make sense now. Great one.

Answer (score 3):

Using `.replaceWith()` function you can add span tag between any text with quotes.

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("h2"). // all p tags
contents(). // select the actual contents of the tags 
filter(function(i,el){   return el.nodeType === 3; }). // only the text nodes
each(function(i, el){ 
    var $el = $(el); // take the text node as a jQuery element
    var replaced = $el.text().replace(/"(.*?)"/g,'<span class="smallcaps">"$1"</span>') // wrap
    $el.replaceWith(replaced); // and replace
    });
  
});
```

```css
.smallcaps {
    color:blue;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<h2>and he said "Hello, i am Nick" and "I am good"</h2>
```

Comment: He wants to wrap any text inside quotes, not only 'Hello, i am Nick'.

Comment: Glad you did (but I never downvote answers, if that was the insinuation).

Answer (score 3):

Use `String.prototype.replace()` method:

```js
var str = document.querySelector('div').textContent;
var reg = /(".*\")+/g
var s = str.replace(reg, function(m){
   return '<span style="color:blue">'+m+'</span>';
})

document.querySelector('div').innerHTML = s;
```

```html
<div>and he said "Hello, I am Nick", some extra</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use the String's [`.replace()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/replace#Specifying_a_string_as_a_parameter) function as follows:

---

(1) If you want to keep the quotes and have them inside the `<span>`:

```js
var source = '---- "xxxx" ---- "xxxx" ----';

var result = source.replace(/"[^"]*"/g, '<span style="color:blue">$&</span>');

console.log(result);
$('#container').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Notes:

1. The `[^"]` sequence in the regular expression defines a set of characters that matches all characters other than a double quote. Therefore, `[^"]*` matches zero or more characters that are not a double quote.
2. The `$&` in the replacement string will be replaced with the matched characters.

---

(2) If you do not want to keep the quotes:

```js
var source = '---- "xxxx" ---- "xxxx" ----';

var result = source.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '<span style="color:blue">$1</span>');

console.log(result);
$('#container').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

1. The parentheses in the regular expression create a capturing group. (Notice that the quotes are not within the capturing group.)
2. The `$1` in the replacement string will be replaced with the first capturing group.

---

(3) If you want to keep the quotes, but have them outside the `<span>`:

```js
var source = '---- "xxxx" ---- "xxxx" ----';

var result = source.replace(/"([^"]*)"/g, '"<span style="color:blue">$1</span>"');

console.log(result);
$('#container').html(result);
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.12.4.min.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Note: This is the same as #2, but the quotes are included in the substitution string, so they are put back in the result string.

Answer (score 0):

If regex is not mandatory, then try this `split-map-join` as well

```js
var text = document.getElementById( "el" ).innerHTML;

function transform(input)
{
  return input.split("\"").map( function(item,index){ if( index % 2 != 0 ){ item = '<span style="color: blue">' + item; } return item }).join("");
}

document.getElementById( "el" ).innerHTML = transform(text)
```

```html
<div id="el">
and he said "Hello, i am Nick"
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
'and he said "Hello, I am Nick"'.replace(/"Hello, I am Nick"/, '<span style="color: blue">$&</span>');
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value.